# MongoDB projection on specific nested properties

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

```
"data" : {
    "visits" : {
        "daily" : {
            "2018-09-05" : 3586,
            "2018-09-06" : 2969,
            "2018-09-07" : 2624,
            "2018-09-08" : 2803,
            "2018-09-09" : 3439,
            "2018-09-10" : 3655
        }
    }
},
```

I have property structure in MongoDB like this, what I am trying to do is, if i have start date and end date, for example (2018-09-06 - 2018-09-07),
I want to get result in this format

```
"data" : {
    "visits" : {
        "daily" : {
            "2018-09-06" : 2969,
            "2018-09-07" : 2624
        }
    }
},
```

Is there any efficient way to do it dynamically? I can do it by putting in projections things like this {"data.visits.daily.2018-09-06": 1, "data.visits.daily.2018-09-07": 1} and it works but it doesn't seem to me like a good solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using **MongoDB 3.4.4** and newer versions:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$addFields": { 
        "data.visits.daily": {
            "$arrayToObject": {
                "$filter": {
                    "input": { "$objectToArray": "$data.visits.daily" },
                    "as": "el",
                    "cond": {
                        "$and": [
                            { "$gte": ["$$el.k", "2018-09-06"] },
                            { "$lte": ["$$el.k", "2018-09-07"] },
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } }
])
```

The above pipeline will yield the final output

```
{
    "data" : {
        "visits" : {
            "daily" : {
                "2018-09-06" : 2969,
                "2018-09-07" : 2624
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

### Explanations

The pipeline can be decomposed to show each individual operator's results.

**[`$objectToArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/)**

**[`$objectToArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/)** enables you to transform the document with dynamic keys 
into an array that contains a element for each field/value pair in the original document. Each element in the return array is a document that contains two fields k and v.

Running the pipeline with just the operator in a **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/)** stage

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "keys": { "$objectToArray": "$data.visits.daily" }
    } }
])
```

yields

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bab6d09b1951fef20a5dce4"),
    "keys" : [ 
        {
            "k" : "2018-09-05",
            "v" : 3586
        }, 
        {
            "k" : "2018-09-06",
            "v" : 2969
        }, 
        {
            "k" : "2018-09-07",
            "v" : 2624
        }, 
        {
            "k" : "2018-09-08",
            "v" : 2803
        }, 
        {
            "k" : "2018-09-09",
            "v" : 3439
        }, 
        {
            "k" : "2018-09-10",
            "v" : 3655
        }
    ]
}
```

**[`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/)**

The **[`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/)** operator acts as a filtering mechanism for the array produced by the **[`$objectToArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/)** operator, works by selecting a subset of the array to return based on the specified condition which 
becomes your query.

Consider the following pipeline which returns an array of the key/value pair that matches the condition `"2018-09-06" <= key <= "2018-09-07"`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "keys": { 
            "$filter": {
                "input": { "$objectToArray": "$data.visits.daily" },
                "as": "el",
                "cond": {
                    "$and": [
                        { "$gte": ["$$el.k", "2018-09-06"] },
                        { "$lte": ["$$el.k", "2018-09-07"] },
                    ]
                }
            }  
        }
    } }
])
```

which yields

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bab6d09b1951fef20a5dce4"),
    "keys" : [ 
        {
            "k" : "2018-09-06",
            "v" : 2969
        }, 
        {
            "k" : "2018-09-07",
            "v" : 2624
        }
    ]
}
```

**[`$arrayToObject`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/)**

This will transform the filtered array above from

```
[ 
    {
        "k" : "2018-09-06",
        "v" : 2969
    }, 
    {
        "k" : "2018-09-07",
        "v" : 2624
    }
]
```

to the original document with the dynamic key

```
{
    "2018-09-06" : 2969,
    "2018-09-07" : 2624
}
```

so running the pipeline

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$project": { 
        "keys": {
            "$arrayToObject": {
                "$filter": {
                    "input": { "$objectToArray": "$data.visits.daily" },
                    "as": "el",
                    "cond": {
                        "$and": [
                            { "$gte": ["$$el.k", "2018-09-06"] },
                            { "$lte": ["$$el.k", "2018-09-07"] },
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } }
])
```

will produce

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bab6d09b1951fef20a5dce4"),
    "keys" : {
        "2018-09-06" : 2969,
        "2018-09-07" : 2624
    }
}
```

But of course you would want to preserve the original schema i.e. the current fields so you would need to use **[`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/)** instead of the **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/)** pipeline used for illustrated.

**[`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/)**

This is is equivalent to a **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/)** stage that explicitly specifies all existing fields in the input documents and adds the new fields. Specifying an existing field name in an **[`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/)** operation causes the original field to be replaced and you would need to use dot notation to to update the embedded data.visits.daily field with the dynamic keys.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using the following aggregation :

```
var startdate = "2018-09-06";
var enddate = "2018-09-09";
db['01'].aggregate(
    [
        {
            $project: {
               daily:{$objectToArray:"$data.visits.daily"}
            }
        },
        {
            $unwind: {
                path : "$daily",

            }
        },
        {
            $addFields: {
                "date": {$dateFromString:{dateString:"$daily.k",format:"%Y-%m-%d"}}
            }
        },
        {
            $match: {
            $and:[{date:{$gte:new Date(startdate)}},{date:{$lte:new Date(enddate)}}]
            }
        },
        {
            $group: {
            _id:"_id",
            daily:{$push:"$daily"}
            }
        },
        {
            $project: {
                "data.visits.daily":{$arrayToObject:"$daily"}
            }
        },
    ]
);
```