# How to query nested objects

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

MongoDB I have one document, I need to get one object,
if `locale.en` then it will return that info
if `locale.fr`' then it will return that info

```
{
   "locale": {
        "en": {
          "dashboard": {
            "DASHBOARD_TITLE": "Some title"
          }
        },
        "fr": {
          "dashboard": {
            "DASHBOARD_TITLE": "Some title french"
          }
        },
        "pr": {
          "dashboard": {
            "DASHBOARD_TITLE": "Some title portugues"
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

How to query this specific object?

```
db.collectionName.find({locale.en})
```

[image]

Comment: do you have a **variable** called `locale` with a property called `en` - oh, wait, that's not valid syntax at all anyway - that's not how you pass anything in javascript

Comment: I just updated with mongo image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using aggregation

Assuming your object has key `locale` like this

```
{
"_id": <Some Object Id>,
"locale": {
  "en": {
    "dashboard": {
      "DASHBOARD_TITLE": "Some title"
    }
  },
  "fr": {
    "dashboard": {
      "DASHBOARD_TITLE": "Some title french"
    }
  },
  "pr": {
    "dashboard": {
      "DASHBOARD_TITLE": "Some title portugues"
    }
  }
 }
}
```

Then aggregation would be

```
[{
"$project": {
  "locale": {
    "$arrayToObject": {
      "$filter": {
        "input": {
          "$objectToArray": "$locale"
        },
        "as": "el",
        "cond": {
          $eq: [
            "$$el.k",
            "en"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
 }
}]
```

Just pass your locale in `$eq` array as second value, I've passed `en` you can use variable here to build query

Playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/7ZHIUx_j1GY

Answer on this question explains the pipeline in detail
[MongoDB projection on specific nested properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52514800/mongodb-projection-on-specific-nested-properties)

Playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/wuv4axIMzCc

Dynamic query : https://mongoplayground.net/p/5ouZif-MIry

Comment: how to bind the dynamic properties. for eg:  `"locale": {` this property needs to change from `locale.$parm1: {`

Comment: @Rijo I am not sure what you are trying to do. Also the dynamic query link you added in answer is not a right mongo query, consider removing it from answer